# MySQL warning of Unknown column that exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

Having found out how to find PHP problems. I am now trying to solve them, but I have no clue on this one.

I made use of mysql_error and I have found:

```
1054: Unknown column 'o.user_id' in 'on clause'
```

Is there something wrong with this:

```
$sql="SELECT o.*, u.user_name, u.email, od.artist_id,cm.nexchange_price

         FROM ".$tableprefix."orders o,".$tableprefix."currency_master cm

        INNER JOIN ".$tableprefix."users u ON o.user_id = u.user_id

        INNER JOIN ".$tableprefix."order_details od ON o.order_id = od.order_id

        WHERE o.order_id = ".GetSQLValueString($orderid,"text")."

         AND o.vorder_currency = cm.vcurrency_code ".$qryopt . " ORDER BY o.order_date DESC";
```

That column exists in the orders table?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a comma after "orders o,", which means that you are trying to join the `currency_master` table with the `users` table, instead of `orders` and `users`. I suppose you wanted to have:

```
$sql="
  SELECT
    o.*, u.user_name, u.email, od.artist_id,cm.nexchange_price
  FROM
    ".$tableprefix."currency_master cm,
    ".$tableprefix."orders o
  INNER JOIN
    ".$tableprefix."users u
  ON
    o.user_id = u.user_id // et cetera"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly! :)